# In the Dresden Universe, does hurting (but not killing) a mortal with magic go against the laws?

Tags: the-dresden-files

I know that the laws of magic prevent (or at least greatly discourage) a spell-slinger to kill or remove a being's free will, but what about just hurting a mortal and not actually killing them?

For instance, would the White Counsel pass judgement on a wizard that used magic to break someone's leg?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, the Laws of Magic are very specific about what you can and can't do. Killing, with magic, is forbidden. Causing bodily harm with magic, or killing using non-magic means, are both within the Laws of Magic (though likely fall afoul of the laws of mortals.)

Harry shows little problems using his kinetic magic rings, for example, to injure humans that are chasing after him.

Answer (score 0):

The one exception would be to cause harm that changes the person.  Such as his apprenticed did in Guilty.  I think it comes down to are you using magic directly on the person or is the damage caused by the forces you are directing ie hitting a body with magically generated force vs. taking a hold of the cells in their body and sending them flying.

For Another great storyline on the can and cant's of actions against mortals with magic.  Read the Iron Druid - Love both series.

Comment: Molly broke a *different* law of magic in Proven Guilty. There is a law specifically forbidding meddling with someone's mind and/or using magic to control their behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reading Turn Coat, where Anastasia explains, that the laws of magic aren't there to enforce justice in general. They are in place only to limit power.

In a hypothetical situation:
A wizard owns a company. But his profit is low, because a vanilla competitor exists nearby. So the wizard is, according to the laws of magic, free to drop by, unnoticed, at his competitor's place of business and cause property damage for which he can't be blamed by vanilla justice and won't be pursued for by supernatural nations, unless the target has their protection. As long as he doesn't kill anyone or twists anyone's mind, no problem.